# Problemas com Data no bootstrap-datepicker.js e bootstrap-timepicker.js

Tags: bootstrap

Amigos, estou precisando de uma ajuda, tentei varias coisas e não consigo resolver o meu problema.

eu tenho os dois arquivos `bootstrap-timepicker.js e bootstrap-datepicker.js`

O que acontece, em meus arquivos eu alterei todas as datas para português mas continua saindo em inglês, exemplo os dias da semana.

Já tentei de tudo e não consigo resolver o problema, alguém consegue me auxiliar?